# Error con Fragments: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

estoy teniendo un pequeño problema al crear fragments, es que me pone un Exception como si getSupportFragmentManager ya se estuviese ejecutando.

El error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: jhon.casique.baccus, PID: 30971
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
> at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1649)
> at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:589)
> at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:285)
> at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14607)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2837)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4349)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4146)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4087)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4060)
> at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1124)
> at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
> at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
> at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
> at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

MI CODIGO

```
public class WineryFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_winery, container, false);

        //Creating wines.
        Wine bembibre = new Wine(
                "Bembibre",
                "Tinto",
                R.drawable.bembibre,
                "Dominio de Tares",
                "http://www.dominiodetares.com/portfolio/bembibre/",
                "Este vino muestra toda la complejidad y la elegancia de la variedad Mencía. En fase visual luce un color rojo picota muy cubierto con tonalidades violáceas en el menisco. En nariz aparecen recuerdos frutales muy intensos de frutas rojas (frambuesa, cereza) y una potente ciruela negra así como tonos florales de la gama de las rosas y violetas, vegetales muy elegantes y complementarios, hojarasca verde, tabaco y maderas aromáticas (sándalo) que le brindan un troque ciertamente perfumado",
                "El Bierzo",
                5);

        bembibre.addGrape("Mencía");

        Wine vegaval = new Wine(
                "Vegaval",
                "Tinto",
                R.drawable.vegaval,
                "Miguel de Calatayud",
                "http://www.vegaval.com/es",
                "Este vino es para gente guay como Jhon ó Gabriela, el gordo no, el no es guay",
                "Valdepeñas",
                4);

        vegaval.addGrape("Tempranillo");

        //View for fragment add tabs.
        FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) root.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        //Adding the first tab.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putSerializable(WineFragment.ARG_WINE, bembibre);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(bembibre.getName()).setIndicator(bembibre.getName()), WineryFragment.class, arguments);

        //Adding the second tab
        arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putSerializable(WineFragment.ARG_WINE, vegaval);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(vegaval.getName()).setIndicator(vegaval.getName()), WineryFragment.class, arguments);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Y este es el código de la actividad

```
package jhon.casique.baccus.controller.activity;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import jhon.casique.baccus.controller.fragments.WineryFragment;

public class WineryActivity extends FragmentContainerActivity {
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new WineryFragment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La verdad que nunca he usado ningún `FragmentTabHost` pero después de mirar la documentación de Android para este método [aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) he visto que nunca llama al mismo fragment dos veces.

En realidad en tu código estás repitiendo la misma clase para dos tabs distintas:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(bembibre.getName()).setIndicator(bembibre.getName()), WineryFragment.class, arguments);
```

ya que haces referencia dos veces a `WineryFragment.class`.

Puedo deducir, por tanto, que el problema está ahí ya que además tu error indica que ya se está ejecutando `FragmentManager`, por lo que tendría sentido que te diera el error en el segundo `tabHost.addTab` ya que has creado uno para el primer vino.

Mi propuesta es que crees un nuevo `Fragment` para cada vino y que después llames desde una clase común a todas las distintas tabs que has creado en diferentes clases mediante `Fragments` con el método `tabHost.addTab`.

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: SI! MUCHAS GRACIAS! ME HAS AYUDADO MUCHO!!

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar el porque del voto negativo?